# Varnish is serving sometime wrong cache theme on desktop or in mobile

Tags: caching, proxies

**Setup** - We have Varnish in front of three drupal backend server. Varnish is serving as a cache and load balancer. Load balancer is using round robin director. It also does the device detection together
with a drupal module (https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_switch_varnish) to switch between the desktop and mobile theme.

**device- detection code (vcl) is below  -**

```
sub vcl_recv {
  call identify_device;
}

sub identify_device {
    unset req.http.X-UA-Device;
    set req.http.X-UA-Device = "pc";

    # Handle that a cookie may override the detection alltogether.
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(?i)X-UA-Device-force") {
        /* ;?? means zero or one ;, non-greedy to match the first. */
        set req.http.X-UA-Device = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "(?i).*X-UA-Device-force=([^;]+);??.*", "\1");
        /* Clean up our mess in the cookie header */
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|; ) *X-UA-Device-force=[^;]+;? *", "\1");
        /* If the cookie header is now empty, or just whitespace, unset it. */
        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^ *$") { unset req.http.Cookie; }
    } else {
        if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "\(compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; \+http://www.google.com/bot.html\)" ||
            (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iPhone" && req.http.User-Agent ~ "\(compatible; Googlebot/2.1; \+http://www.google.com/bot.html")) {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-smart"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)ipad")        
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-tablet"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)ip(hone|od)") 
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-smart"; }
        /* how do we differ between an android phone and an android tablet?
           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341637/how-do-detect-android-tablets-in-general-useragent */
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)android.*(mobile|mini)") 
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-smart"; }
        // android 3/honeycomb was just about tablet-only, and any phones will probably handle a bigger page layout.
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)android 3")              
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-tablet"; }
        /* Opera Mobile */
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Opera Mobi")                  
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-smart"; }
        // May very well give false positives towards android tablets. Suggestions welcome.
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)android")         
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-tablet"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet")         
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-tablet"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "hp-tablet.*TouchPad")         
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-tablet"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Kindle/3")        
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-tablet"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Touch.+Tablet PC")           
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-tablet"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Mobile.+Firefox")     
                    { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-other"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "^HTC" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "Fennec" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "IEMobile" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "BlackBerry" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "BB10.*Mobile" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "GT-.*Build/GINGERBREAD" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "SymbianOS.*AppleWebKit") 
                    {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-smart";
                    }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)symbian" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^sonyericsson" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^nokia" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^samsung" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^lg" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)bada" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)blazer" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)cellphone" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)iemobile" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)midp-2.0" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)u990" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)netfront" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)opera mini" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)palm" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)nintendo wii" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)playstation portable" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)portalmmm" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)proxinet" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)sonyericsson" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)symbian" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)windows\ ?ce" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)winwap" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)eudoraweb" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)htc" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)240x320" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)avantgo") 
                    {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-other";
                    }
    }
}


sub vcl_hash {
    #Default Hash
    hash_data(req.url);
   if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    #hash based on device type
    if (req.http.X-UA-Device ~ "^mobile") {
        hash_data(req.http.host+req.http.X-UA-Device);
    }

    //return (hash);
}

**PHP code (written in module) which switch the theme is below -** 

/**
 * Implements hook_custom_theme()
*/
function yt_switchtheme_custom_theme(){
  // Detect if this is a mobile device.

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_UA_DEVICE']) && strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_X_UA_DEVICE'], 'mobile')) {

    // Bail if this is an admin page and we don't respect admin pages.
    if (path_is_admin(current_path()) && !variable_get('mobile_switch_varnish_use_on_admin_pages', FALSE)) {
      return;
    }
    // Fetch the device type from the server variable.
     $device_type = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_X_UA_DEVICE'], 7);
    // If the mobile theme for device is empty (unlikely) or set to 'default' then return the default mobile theme.
    if (!variable_get('mobile_switch_varnish_theme_' . $device_type, 'default') || variable_get('mobile_switch_varnish_theme_' . $device_type, 'default') == 'default') {
      return variable_get('mobile_switch_varnish_theme_default', 'mobile_jquery');
    }
    // Else it's been set specifically; use this theme setting instead.
    else {
      return variable_get('mobile_switch_varnish_theme_' . $device_type, 'default');
    }
  }
}
```

Now problem is usually it serves desktop theme and mobile theme right on desktop and mobile device respectively but sometime it serve the mobile theme on desktop and vice-versa.

How can I stop it from happening?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, I'm going to try using this: https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_switch_varnish
hope it works...

Comment: Have you tried this solution yet?  If so, can you report if/how it soves this problem?

Comment: We are already using above module for switching the theme based on http header  'HTTP_X_UA_DEVICE' which is set by device-detection.vcl file. But  the problem is not solved. Some time it shows mobile theme on desktop and vice-versa. So i am looking on theory behind it. What cause this issue.?